# android sqlite.query not returning the row

Tags: android, android-sqlite

A row has been inserted into the sqlite database via some UI action. I can see the row if I drop to `adb shell`, but not able to retreive it back in the android code.

Can you please let me know what could be a possible issue?

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM daily  WHERE day = \"Sun\"";
    Log.d("DBLOG", selectQuery);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Log.d("DBLOG", "" + c.getCount());
```

In adb shell, I dropped to sqlite3 prompt and can see the result for the exact same query.

#### Update:

Ok maybe date is not being used correctly by me. But even tough querying on other field also gives no output.
[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer, but are you really storing your dates as integers such as `6082017`?  I think you should be using text.  Maybe the shell is marshalling the number to text.

Comment: That's not the recommended format to store dates... https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: @Tim Updated. Ok but even the query on other field is not returning data. Please see udpated screenshot.

Comment: @cricket_007 Updated. Ok but even the query on other field is not returning data. Please see udpated screenshot.

Comment: I think you're querying an entirely different database

Comment: `... WHERE day = 'Sun'`

Comment: @ModularSynth tried that too.. no luck yet.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am sure it's correct. I went to /data/data/<package-name>/databases . Rechecked twice

Comment: No, in the app itself

Comment: ... or you'd better store your dates as ISO strings (`YYY-MM-DD`) and check the weekday by using the `strftime()` function with the `%w` set to **0** (Sunday). And the WeekDay column becomes useless.

Comment: OOps.. I forgot a Y, my bad. It's `YYYY-MM-DD`.